# Button in SideBarOther widget not showing up on all pages

Tags: html, facebook, widgets

An item in SideBarOther shows up on the main article listing page, but when I select an article (same page layout, the article replaces the listing), the item isn't there. There are two items in SideBarOther, and only the 2nd one has this problem (see code below). If I remove the first one, it is correctly gone from from both the listing page and article page, and the 2nd one still only shows up on the listing page. I'm using an unmodified "News Magazine Theme 640" theme.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/[our-page]/[our number]" title="[our name]" 
target="_blank"><img src="../pics/fbook_button.jpg" boder="0" alt="[our name]"></a>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like 
href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/[our name]/[our number]" layout="box_count" 
show_faces="false" width="50"></fb:like>
```

NO, I am not confusing which item is not appearing - the local directory reference ../pics on the first item works on all pages. The Facebook Like button is the one that isn't appearing on all pages.

This is not hosted by Wordpress, rather Wordpress v. 2.92 is installed on our website.

(I tried the official wordpress forum, and got no reply.)

Thanks

UPDATE
I "viewed page source" in Firefox, and THE CODE IS THERE on the article page, and it's IDENTICAL to the listing page. So why isn't it displayed??? I tried the Opera browser, same results. I added another copy of the first widget, and two of them appear on the listing page, and on the article page - the box automatically adjusted to accommodate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a conflict with the Facebook Share plugin.  If you add the `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>` code somewhere before the Facebook Share code, the like button then works, and the share button still works.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, please provide links to the site and pages that display this issue.

Since your second item seems to be a script - first step would be to verify is it being output in page source. Otherwise it is hard to guess is problem with script not echoed or script not running.

PS there had been important security fixes since version 2.9.2, please consider upgrading as soon as possible.

Comment: There's a client privacy issue with posting the URL.  What would you do to tell - "is problem with script not echoed or script not running?"  Thanks.

Comment: I just updated to 3.04. Fast & painless.  The problems remains.